# How to get all "objects" that are using one specifc column from a table

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Sql server 2008 R2 and from some reason, for one field from my database, the values are changed than the one the users insert.
 I suspect it is a job, a procedure, something that uses that field, and somehow changes the initial value. therefore I need to find all "objects" that have that field specified in its body, as a manor of speaking.
 Any clues?

Thank you so much, Bogdan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becouse I did not get any suitable answer I want to help others.
So one can use:

```
DECLARE @SearchTextInformation NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @SearchTextInformation = '<the name of the table, view, or object you want to find>' ;
SELECT [ao].[name], [asm].[definition] 
FROM sys.all_objects ao 
JOIN sys.all_sql_modules asm 
ON [ao].[object_id] = [asm].[object_id] 
WHERE [asm].[definition] LIKE '%' + @SearchTextInformation+ '%'
```

It will return, all objects that in their description it is mentioned your "object".
Best regards, Bogdan

Answer (score 1):

I find SQL Search from RedGate really useful for stuff like this:

[SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/)

It's a free tool that plugs in to SSMS that looks through all databases on an instance and finds text in there really quickly.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can RIGHT-CLICK the table and `VIEW DEPENDENCIES`. This will show some details.